# Black border on FigureCanvas upon changing size in pyqt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm trying to embed a matplotlib (version 3.0.0) figure into a pyqt5 gui (version 5.9.2). Therefore, I'm creating a canvas and adding it to the layout. However, when I start changing size properties like `canvas.setFixedSize(500,500)` and then change the gui size by dragging the window corner, I end up with a black border: [image: black border].

This behaviour can be fixed by adding `fig.patch.set_facecolor('#ffffff')`. However, I'm wondering if this behaviour is expected or if there is another way of preventing the black border to appear?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QGridLayout,QPushButton, QApplication, QSizePolicy)

from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets, is_pyqt5
if is_pyqt5():
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
        FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
else:
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
        FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        layout = QGridLayout(self._main)        

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        # enabling one of following options leads to black frame
        #canvas.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed) 
        #canvas.setFixedSize(500,500)

        #which can be fixed by
        #fig.patch.set_facecolor('#ffffff')

        layout.addWidget(canvas)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Check whether there is already a running QApplication (e.g., if running
    # from an IDE).
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not qapp:
        qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

Comment: Which matplotlib version is this? Which pyqt version? I do not see a black frame when running either of both options. One thing to note though: Compared to [the official example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) you added `pyplot` and used it to create the figure. This is generally discouraged, because it might lead to all kinds of problems. you may use `fig = Figure(); ax = fig.subplots()`  instead.

Comment: I edited my question to include also the used versions (3.0.0 & 5.9.2). Using Figure() directly didn't help. However, I was executing this code in Jupyter so far. Rerunning it directly from the command prompt lead to a satisfying result without black border. So this behaviour might be caused by Jupyter?

Comment: I see. I can reproduce in jupyter - that is an important piece of information. And unfortunately, I have no idea what's causing it. Curiously though, if I create some pyplot plot like `plt.plot([1,3,2]); plt.show()` using the default inline backend, and then copy the resulting figure to any image viewer, it will also appear black. So for now a setting the alpha channel of the background patch to 1, just as you do it in the question is probably the best workaround.

Comment: Oh, but it seems to indeed be coupled to the import of pyplot. So if I remove the line that imports pyplot (and replace the figure creation as in my first comment), restart the kernel and run the cell, it's working correctly. Can you reproduce?

Comment: Yep, I can reproduce. Importing pyplot and creating the plot with ```fig  = Figure()``` is working correctly. However using pyplot in any other cell and then creating the plot with  ```fig  = Figure()``` leads to described behaviour. So I guess I should just avoid using ```pyplot```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Described problem only occured when called in Jupyter. Switching from inline to the agg backend with `%matplotlib agg` solves the problem.